Good way to store data for my programs to reference (Python)?
I am creating a game with multiple "rooms" and each "room" has numerous data values associated with it (id number, description, rooms it connects to, etc). I was originally thinking of creating a dictionary with all the data in its own script that i can import when needed. However, it has occurred to me that rebuilding the dictionary each time the main script has to reference room information would severely impact performance. Is there a more efficient way to store this information? All of it should remain the same at init, as the ones that will change throughout the game will be stored in the player save file instead.
I made a system where the script saves player data to an xml file, but it's been a huge pain and I am hoping I do not have to do it again.
Edit 1: Been attempting to make the dictionary, trying to automate it as much as I can given that there will eventually be much more data in it. It's also not quite operational right now but thats okay.
# travelTypes = set(["teleport", "walk", "fly", "ride"])
# alignments = set(["allied", "neutral", "enemy"])

class Location(dict):
   def __init__(self, rooms, alignment):
      self._mydict = {
          self.alignment : alignment,
          self.rooms : rooms
      }

class Room(dict):
    def __init__(self, hidden, pathways):
        self._mydict = {
            self.hidden : hidden,
            self.pathways : pathways
        }

class Pathway(dict):
    def __init__(self, hidden, travelType):
        self._mydict = {
            self.hidden : hidden,
            self.travelType : travelType
        }

p1 = Pathway(True, "teleport")

voidRoom = Room(True, [p1])
villageEntrance = Room(False, [p1])

void = Location([voidRoom], "neutral")
village = Location([villageEntrance], "good")

world = {
    "void" : void,
    "village" : village
}

def locationDataRetrieval(path):
    val = world.get(path)
    return val

print(world)

Edit 2: I am simply editing the code as I figure it out, don't mind me it's the first time I've worked with dictionaries to this extent.

a dictionary with all the data in its own script that i can import when needed This sounds like a fine solution.  You shouldn't have to worry about performance issues.

player data to an xml file It's usually much easier to work with json files than xml files.

If this were a truly massive "map" you might use a network database like graphql but that seems like overkill here.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@mzjn I just mean I had problems getting it to work in the past, it works fine now. I have not sent any code yet because I am looking for general ideas not a specific solution to a problem.

I don't know the complexity of your project. If you are going to store more data, it may be more correct/effective to use a database. If you have a more limited dataset, i think there may be two solutions, .yaml or json.
json
#rooms.py
{
 "room1": {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Dark Hole",
    "connections": ["room2", "room3"]
},
"room2": {
    "id": 2,
    "description": "Large Hall",
    "connections": ["room1"]
}
}

  # main.py
 import json

 with open('rooms.json', 'r') as file:
    rooms = json.load(file)

.yaml
#rooms.yaml
room1:
  id: 1
  description: Dark Hole
  connections: 
     - room2
     - room3

# main.py 
import yaml

with open('rooms.yaml', 'r') as file:
   rooms = yaml.safe_load(file)


#rooms.py That should be rooms.json.
